# Can auto property backing field names be relied upon?

Tags: c#, reflection

Short version: Can I rely on auto property backing fields having names in a certain format? Like "`<my_member>k__BackingField`"?

I am writing some serialisation code, which uses reflection to figure out which fields/properties to serialise.

Currently it serialises auto properties using `Type.GetMembers`, then using `PropertyInfo.GetGetMethod` and `PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod` on property members, checking that they have the `CompilerGeneratedAttribute` (to make sure they are auto), then invoking those methods to get and set the underlying value.

This is usually fine, but it fails for e.g. C# 6 "read-only auto-properties", which lack a setter, but which should conceptually work ok because I do support serialising read-only fields.

So I wonder if I should just find the backing field for auto properties and serialise that instead - but I can't find any API to get a `PropertyInfo`'s corresponding backing field - instead I just see that there happens to be a `PropertyInfo`, and then a `FieldInfo` with a name like "`<my_member>k__BackingField`" - but I don't know if I can rely on that, or if it's something that may change between compilations/compiler versions.

Comment: You can't rely on the naming to be consistent across versions. How do you expect to serialize a read-only property? It would make sense to use only properties with a setter for serialization

Comment: You can find all these using GetMembers( BindiingFlags.Instance | BinidngFlags.NonPublic)

Comment: @a-ctor: Thanks! I don't suppose you could point me to any docs that mention naming? I really can't find anything (though maybe that's evidence in itself!).

I serialise read-only fields since that's possible with reflection, so I expect to serialise read-only properties by serialising the read-only backing field, the same way I do a normal field (so by not using the setter & getter).

sTrenat - thanks! I am already doing that (hence how I found the backing field names), I just need to know whether I can depend on the backing field name being consistent, or if I'm never meant to see it...

Comment: @BenHymers you could search in the roslyn docs but I think you search will turn up empty. You should not be setting readonly fields outside of the constructor since the compiler could do optimizations based on readonly. I would go with the requirement of using `string Prop { get; private set; }` this way you can set the field safely.

Comment: @a-ctor: Thanks again :) I have searched around some more now that I have better words to search for, and it does seem that the name is implementation-defined and not dependable, so I will give up on this quest. And thanks for the extra info on the readonly fields - sounds like that is also in the 'implementation-defined' category!

Answer (score 0):

No.

The language standard do not restrict the auto generated backing field's name of auto-properties.

Here's my way to get the FieldInfo of auto property's backing field:

```
public static FieldInfo? GetAutoPropertyBackingField(this PropertyInfo pi, bool strictCheckIsAutoProperty = false)
{
    if (strictCheckIsAutoProperty && !StrictCheckIsAutoProperty(pi)) return null;

    var gts = pi.DeclaringType?.GetGenericArguments();
    var accessor = pi.GetGetMethod(true);
    var msilBytes = accessor?.GetMethodBody()?.GetILAsByteArray();
    var rtk = null != msilBytes
        ? accessor!.IsStatic
            ? GetAutoPropertyBakingFieldMetadataTokenInGetMethodOfStatic(msilBytes)
            : GetAutoPropertyBakingFieldMetadataTokenInGetMethodOfInstance(msilBytes)
        : -1;

    accessor = pi.GetSetMethod(true);
    msilBytes = accessor?.GetMethodBody()?.GetILAsByteArray();
    if (null != msilBytes)
    {
        var wtk = accessor!.IsStatic
            ? GetAutoPropertyBakingFieldMetadataTokenInSetMethodOfStatic  (msilBytes)
            : GetAutoPropertyBakingFieldMetadataTokenInSetMethodOfInstance(msilBytes);

        if (-1 != wtk)
        {
            if (wtk == rtk)
            {
                var wfi = pi.Module.ResolveField(wtk, gts, null);
                if (!strictCheckIsAutoProperty || null == wfi || StrictCheckIsAutoPropertyBackingField(pi, wfi)) return wfi;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    if (-1 == rtk) return null;

    var rfi = pi.Module.ResolveField(rtk, gts, null);
    return !strictCheckIsAutoProperty || null == rfi || StrictCheckIsAutoPropertyBackingField(pi, rfi) ? rfi : null;
}

private static bool StrictCheckIsAutoProperty            (PropertyInfo pi)               => null != pi.GetCustomAttribute<CompilerGeneratedAttribute>();
private static bool StrictCheckIsAutoPropertyBackingField(PropertyInfo pi, FieldInfo fi) => fi.Name == "<" + pi.Name + ">k__BackingField";

private static int GetAutoPropertyBakingFieldMetadataTokenInGetMethodOfStatic  (byte[] msilBytes) => 6 == msilBytes.Length &&                                                 0x7E == msilBytes[0] && 0x2A == msilBytes[5] ? BitConverter.ToInt32(msilBytes, 1) : -1;
private static int GetAutoPropertyBakingFieldMetadataTokenInSetMethodOfStatic  (byte[] msilBytes) => 7 == msilBytes.Length &&                         0x02 == msilBytes[0] && 0x80 == msilBytes[1] && 0x2A == msilBytes[6] ? BitConverter.ToInt32(msilBytes, 2) : -1;
private static int GetAutoPropertyBakingFieldMetadataTokenInGetMethodOfInstance(byte[] msilBytes) => 7 == msilBytes.Length && 0x02 == msilBytes[0]                         && 0x7B == msilBytes[1] && 0x2A == msilBytes[6] ? BitConverter.ToInt32(msilBytes, 2) : -1;
private static int GetAutoPropertyBakingFieldMetadataTokenInSetMethodOfInstance(byte[] msilBytes) => 8 == msilBytes.Length && 0x02 == msilBytes[0] && 0x03 == msilBytes[1] && 0x7D == msilBytes[2] && 0x2A == msilBytes[7] ? BitConverter.ToInt32(msilBytes, 3) : -1;
```

The last 6 single line methods' code looks maybe a little messed since the browser uses a non-fixed width font.

The 2 strict check methods are adapted to M$ dotnetfx runtimes.

The key code use MSIL bytes generated by compiler to find the auto property's backing field in last 4 methods. They works for M$'s dotnetfx4x and dotnet5, and maybe all M$'s dotnetfx runtimes.

If you use it with mono or other frameworks, you can peek the compiler emitted auto property's attributes, backing field's name and setter/getter's IL bytes with dnSpy or other similar tools and then modify the 6 single line methods to adapt them. And of course you can add some other strict checks to ensure the code works correct on the fx which your program is running on.

Answer (score -1):

I'll go against the grain and say I believe you can rely on the backing field always following the same naming format.
This is at least true for the current compiler Roslyn, so as long as you aren't using an older compiler, or creating a library that targets older versions of C#, I'd say yes.

```
internal static string MakeBackingFieldName(string propertyName)
{
    Debug.Assert((char)GeneratedNameKind.AutoPropertyBackingField == 'k');
    return "<" + propertyName + ">k__BackingField";
}
```

The only time `propertyName` will be different is when interfaces are involved.

Here is the code that generates the `propertyName`, taking interfaces into account. Looks like it may be changed soon though.
The `name` parameter will always match the identifier.

```
public static string GetMemberName(string name, TypeSymbol explicitInterfaceTypeOpt, string aliasQualifierOpt)
{
    if ((object)explicitInterfaceTypeOpt == null)
    {
        return name;
    }

    // TODO: Revisit how explicit interface implementations are named.
    // CONSIDER (vladres): we should never generate identical names for different methods.

    string interfaceName = explicitInterfaceTypeOpt.ToDisplayString(SymbolDisplayFormat.ExplicitInterfaceImplementationFormat);

    PooledStringBuilder pooled = PooledStringBuilder.GetInstance();
    StringBuilder builder = pooled.Builder;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(aliasQualifierOpt))
    {
        builder.Append(aliasQualifierOpt);
        builder.Append("::");
    }

    foreach (char ch in interfaceName)
    {
        // trim spaces to match metadata name (more closely - could still be truncated)
        if (ch != ' ')
        {
            builder.Append(ch);
        }
    }

    builder.Append(".");
    builder.Append(name);

    return pooled.ToStringAndFree();
}
```